# Как узнать какая именно кнопка была нажата PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Хочу написать браузер. Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как делать любое количество вкладок, удалять их и вообще в целом вносить любые другие изменения.

Как я могу узнать какая кнопка именно была нажата, т.е. ее номер?

```
class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,0,0);")

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.buttons = [Button() for i in range(100)]
        i = -1
        for button in self.buttons:
            i+=1             
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printer(i))   #Так все время i = 99, я бы хотел, чтобы i был равен номеру нажатой кнопки      
            self.layout.addWidget(button,i//30,i%30)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def printer(self):
        self.buttons[num].setText(f"{num}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,0,0);")
        self.setMinimumSize(30, 30)
        self.setMaximumSize(30, 30) 


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.buttons = [Button() for i in range(100)]
        
#        i = -1
        for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
#            i+=1             
            button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, num=i: self.printer(num))   
            self.layout.addWidget(button, i//30, i%30)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def printer(self, num):
        self.buttons[num].setText(f"{num}")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит  ch?

Comment: @Bitchdragon  `checked`  - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: @Bitchdragon пожалуйста.